# Ellipse bounding a rectangle

Tags: math

Maths101 question - does anyone know how to calculate an ellipse (width/height) that will enclose a given rectangle. Obviously there is no single ellipse - I'm after an algorithm that will give me various width/height combinations - or perhaps the smallest area of ellipse? It's for a GUI, so an aesthetically pleasing ratio of height/width is what I'm looking for.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Bill the Lizard.  the line between math and programming is blurry at best, and in this case, this is completely relevant to progamming.

I need to draw a gradient that is inside a rectangle.  The best way to do that is to determine the points that are on an ellipse that circumscribe my rectangle.  Bam.  Math, sucka.

Comment: Not relevant to programming. The key to answer this question is getting ellipse-defining coordinates from the rectangle-defining coordinates. The answer to that is a mathematical formula, not an algorithm.

Comment: If it's not relevant to programming, why was I programming when I suddenly wanted to know the answer to this question, and why have I only ever wanted to know the answer to this sort of question while programming or while in a math class, and why did googling for the mathematical answer to this lead me most relevantly to this programming site? Seems to me the decision to mark this off-topic is applying an overly-literal definition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The equation for a ellipse centered in the origin is

```
(x/A)^2 + (y/B)^2 = 1
```

Now if you want to enclose a rectangle of MxN with a eclipse you can move its center to the origin of coordinates. The top right coordinates are `(M/2,N/2)`, replacing in the ellipse equation you have a formula you can use to solve B given A (or A given B).

If you have a rectangle of 4x2, the top-right coordinates are (2,1), replacing you have the `(2/A)^2 + (1/B)^2 = 1`, then if `A=4` solving for B gives `B=1/sqrt(1-(1/2)^2)`.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation - makes total sense now.

Answer (score 28):

If you give your ellipse the same aspect ratio as the rectangle, you can work on the basis that what you want is a circle enclosing a square then stretched as if you've transformed the square into the required rectangle.

For a square with half side length = 1, the radius of the circle would be sqrt(2).

So, sweeping *theta* from 0 - 360', the ellipse's coordinate points will be:

- x = cos(theta) * sqrt(2) * rect.width + x.center;
- y = sin(theta) * sqrt(2) * rect.height + y.center;

where rect.width and rect.height are the *half* widths of the relevant sides.

Comment: actually it's not quite right yet - I'm still working on it...

Comment: ok, I think the maths is actually right now.  I've tested the formulae on Grapher.app

Comment: This is perfect.  To be absolutely clear, you can get the dimensions of the bounding ellipse by just multiplying the dimensions of the rectangle by sqrt(2).

Comment: If you want to change the aspect ratio you can use width' = sqrt(rect.width^2 + ratio^2 * rect.height^2) and height' = width' / ratio with ratio being the requested aspect ratio (width/height) for the ellipse.

Comment: I had the same (programming) issue recently, and came across this answer after posting the question to math. If anybody's still interested, I think we have a more general solution there, http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2149677/semi-major-minor-axes-of-circumscribed-ellipse-enclosing-a-given-rectangle/2150970#2150970  And see JeanMarie's answer above that for the complete discussion. Note that your "sqrt(2) answer" corresponds to our n=1 case.

Comment: @JohnForkosh Aesthetically, I think for layout purposes I still prefer the `n = 1` case since a rectangle subsequently enclosing the eclipse would also maintains the same aspect ratio.

Comment: As JeanMarie said, it's all in the eye of the beholder. And in Scotty's original sense of "smallest area", above, you're also (in addition to your "subsequently circumscribed rectangle") quantitatively right. Under the "aspect-ratio constraint" width/height=(a/b)^n, it's n=1 that minimizes the ellipse area pi*ab, completely independently of width,height.

Answer (score 25):

1. Ellipse formula is (x/A)^2+(y/B)^2=1, where A and B are radiuses of ellipse
2. Rectangle sides are Rw and Rh
3. Let's assume we want ellipse with same proportions as rectangle; then, if we image square in circle (A=B,Rq=Rh) and squeeze it, we well keep ratio of ellipse A/B same as ratio of rectangle sides Rw/Rh;

This leads us to following system of equations:
(x/A)^2+(y/B)^2=1
A/B=Rw/Rh

Lets solve it:
A=B*(Rw/Rh) 
(Rh/2B)^2+(Rh/2B)^2=1 
Rh=sqrt(2)*B

And final solution:
A=Rw/sqrt(2)
B=Rh/sqrt(2)

Example:
[image: ellipse]

Answer (score 2):

Experimentally, I found that an ellipse defined by a rectangle that is sqrt(2) larger than the inner rectangle works.  So pass sqrt(2) to this function, and you will get the appropriate rectangle:

RectangleF boundingEllipse = GetScaledRectangle(innerRect, Convert.ToSingle(Math.Sqrt(2d)));

private RectangleF GetScaledRectangle(RectangleF rect, float scale)
{
    float width = rect.Width * scale;
    float height = rect.Height * scale;

```
float gap = width - rect.Width;
float left = rect.Left - (gap / 2f);

gap = height - rect.Height;
float top = rect.Top - (gap / 2f);

return new RectangleF(left, top, width, height);
```

}

Answer (score 1):

Assuming you mean circumscribed (which is more precise than "enclosed"), you can read about [how to circumscribe a rectangle here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Circumscribed_circle). From there, you can stretch it to rectangular, as Alnitak says.