# Algorithm for drawing random comic-style clouds

Tags: algorithm, 2d

I am trying to figure out an algorithm for drawing random shapes of this kind, knowing the size of the largest rectangle that can be inscribed in them:

[image: comic-style cloud]

I would like to have variable texts fit inside the clouds, some of which may be quite short while others may be a couple of sentences long; that is why I cannot go for a predefined size.

My current approach is the following:

1. Create the largest circle that can be inscribed in the rectangle, using its shortest side as the circle's diameter.
2. Create another circle of random size with its center located somewhere on the edge of the first circle.
3. Find the intersection points between both circles and choose a random one.
4. Place another random sized circle centered at the chosen point. Find intersections with prior circles (except for those covered by a circle) and repeat until all remaining intersections occur outside the rectangle.

My hope is that, by placing circles in the intersection points between other circles, I will cover all the required area in less steps than I would if I placed them in random locations inside the rectangle, by minimizing the number of circles placed in areas that are already fully covered by prior circles.

The first trial has yielded this ugly thing:

[image: ugliest cloud]

But I find a couple of problems in it:

1. Even though all remaining intersections occur outside the rectangle, not all of it is covered, as its bottom-left corner is visible in blue underneath a white circle.
2. I don't know how to draw the outline with the little notches.

Does anybody know a mechanism to draw these kinds of shapes randomly? Thanks.

EDIT:

Following et_l's excellent suggestion, I have put together this suboptimal implementation, giving still not quite the desired result, but much, much better than my own initial trial:

```js
function vector(a, b)
{
    if (!(this instanceof vector)) return new vector(a, b);
    if (a instanceof vector && b instanceof vector) {
        this.x = b.x - a.x;
        this.y = b.y - a.y;
    }
    else {
        this.x = a;
        this.y = b;
    }
}

vector.prototype =
{
    get lengthSq()
    {
        return this.x * this.x + this.y * this.y;
    },
    get length()
    {
        return Math.sqrt(this.lengthSq);
    },
    get angle()
    {
        return (Math.PI / 2) + Math.atan2(this.x, this.y);
    },
    distanceTo:function(x, y)
    {
        if (arguments.length == 1) return new vector(this, arguments[0]).length; 
        return new vector(this, new vector(x, y)).length;
    },
    clone: function()
    {
        return new vector(this.x, this.y);
    },
    normalize: function()
    {
        var l = this.length;
        this.x /= l;
        this.y /= l;
        return this;
    },
    get normalized()
    {
        return this.clone().normalize();
    },
    add: function(x, y)
    {
        if (x instanceof vector) return this.add(x.x, x.y);
        this.x += x;
        this.y += y;
        return this;
    },
    scale: function(x, y)
    {
        if (y === undefined) y = x;
        this.x *= x;
        this.y *= y;
        return this;
    },
    scaled: function(x, y)
    {
        return this.clone().scale(x, y);
    }
};

vector.add = function(v1, v2)
{
    return v1.clone().add(v2);
};

vector.dot = function(v1, v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.x + v1.y * v2.y;
};

vector.cross = function(v1, v2)
{
    return v1.x * v2.y - v1.y * v2.x;
}

function line(p1, p2)
{
    if (!(this instanceof line)) {
        if (arguments.length == 0) return new line();
        if (arguments.length == 2) return new line(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
        if (arguments.length == 4) return new line(arguments[0], arguments[1], arguments[2], arguments[3])
    }
    if (arguments.length == 0) {
        this.p1 = new vector(0, 0);
        this.p2 = new vector(0, 0);    
    }
    else if (arguments.length == 2) {
        this.p1 = p1;
        this.p2 = p2;    
    }
    else if (arguments.length == 4) {
        this.p1 = new vector(arguments[0], arguments[1]);
        this.p2 = new vector(arguments[2], arguments[3]);
    }
}

line.prototype =
{
    get angle()
    {
        return new vector(this.p1, this.p2).angle;
    },
    get lengthSq()
    {
        return new vector(this.p1, this.p2).lengthSq;
    },
    get length()
    {
        return new vector(this.p1, this.p2).length;
    },
    distanceTo: function(p, extend)
    {
        var pp;
        var v1 = new vector(this.p1, p);
        var v2 = new vector(this.p1, this.p2);
        var v2len2 = v2.lengthSq;
        var disc = v2len2 == 0 ? -1 : vector.dot(v1, v2) / v2len2;
        if (!extend && disc < 0) pp = this.p1;
        else if (!extend && disc > 1) pp = this.p2;
        else pp = vector.add(this.p1, v2.scaled(disc));
        return new vector(p, pp).length;
    },
    intersect:function(other)
    {
        var otx, oty, tdx, tdy, odx, ody, cross1, cross2, cross3, t;
        tdx = this.p2.x - this.p1.x;
        tdy = this.p2.y - this.p1.y;
        odx = other.p2.x - other.p1.x;
        ody = other.p2.y - other.p1.y;
        cross1 = tdx * ody - odx * tdy;
        if (cross1 == 0) return null;
        var overZero = cross1 > 0;
        otx = this.p1.x - other.p1.x;
        oty = this.p1.y - other.p1.y;
        cross2 = tdx * oty - tdy * otx;
        if (cross2 < 0 == overZero) return null;
        cross3 = odx * oty - ody * otx;
        if ((cross3 < 0) == overZero) return null;
        if ((cross2 > cross1 == overZero) || (cross3 > cross1 == overZero)) return null;
        t = cross3 / cross1;
        var r = { x:undefined, y:undefined };
        r.x = this.p1.x + (t * tdx);
        r.y = this.p1.y + (t * tdy);
        return r;
    }
};

function ellipse(x, y, width, height, angle, stroke, fill, precision)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;
    this.angle = angle;
    if (stroke) {
        var els = stroke.split(' ');
        this.stroke = els[0];
        if (els.length > 1) this.lineWidth = parseFloat(els[1]);
    }
    this.fill = fill;
    this.precision = precision || 5;
}

ellipse.prototype =
{
    get center()
    {
        return new vector(this.x, this.y);
    },
    setStroke: function(value)
    {
        var els = value.split(' ');
        this.stroke = els[0];
        if (els.length > 1) this.lineWidth = parseFloat(els[1]);
        return this;
    },
    setFill: function(value)
    {
        this.fill = value;
        return this;
    },
    clone: function()
    {
        return new ellipse(this.x, this.y, this.width, this.height, this.angle, this.stroke + (this.lineWidth !== undefined ? ' ' + this.lineWidth : ''), this.fill, this.precision)
    },
    angleAt: function(x, y)
    {
        if (arguments.length == 1) return new vector(x.x - this.x, x.y - this.y).angle;
        return new vector(x - this.x, y - this.y).angle;
    },
    pointAt: function(angle)
    {
        var cost = Math.cos(this.angle), sint = Math.sin(this.angle);
        var cosa = Math.cos(angle), sina = Math.sin(angle);
        var x = this.x + (this.width * cosa * cost - this.height * sina * sint);
        var y = this.y + (this.width * cosa * sint + this.height * sina * cost);
        return new vector(x, y);
    },
    inflate: function(x, y)
    {
        if (y === undefined) y = x;
        if (typeof x == 'string') {
            if (x.substr(-1) == '%') this.width *= 1 + parseFloat(x) / 100;
            else this.width += parseFloat(x);
        }
        else this.width += x;
        if (typeof y == 'string') {
            if (y.substr(-1) == '%') this.height *= 1 + parseFloat(y) / 100;
            else this.height += parseFloat(y);
        }
        else this.height += y;
        return this;
    },
    randomPoint: function()
    {
        return this.pointAt(Math.random() * Math.PI * 2);
    },
    intersect: function(other)
    {
        var r = [];
        var lt = new line(), ot = new line();
        var tcos = Math.cos(this.angle), tsin = Math.sin(this.angle);
        var ocos = Math.cos(other.angle), osin = Math.sin(other.angle);
        lt.p1 = { x:this.x + (this.width * tcos), y:this.y + (this.width * tsin) };
        var o0 = { x:other.x + (other.width * ocos), y:other.y + (other.width * osin) };
        for (var ta = 1; ta < 360; ta += this.precision) {
            var x, y, trads = ta * Math.PI / 180;
            x = this.x + (this.width * Math.cos(trads) * tcos - this.height * Math.sin(trads) * tsin);
            y = this.y + (this.width * Math.cos(trads) * tsin + this.height * Math.sin(trads) * tcos);
            lt.p2 = { x:x, y:y };
            ot.p1 = o0;
            for (var oa = 1; oa < 360; oa += other.precision) {
                var orads = oa * Math.PI / 180;
                x = other.x + (other.width * Math.cos(orads) * ocos - other.height * Math.sin(orads) * osin);
                y = other.y + (other.width * Math.cos(orads) * osin + other.height * Math.sin(orads) * ocos);
                ot.p2 = { x:x, y:y };
                var i = lt.intersect(ot);
                if (i) r.push(i);
                ot.p1 = ot.p2;
            }
            ot.p2 = { x:other.x + (other.width * ocos), y:other.y + (other.width * osin) };
            var i = lt.intersect(ot);
            if (i) r.push(i);
            lt.p1 = lt.p2;
        }
        lt.p2 = { x:this.x + (this.width * tcos), y:this.y + (this.width * tsin) };
        ot.p1 = o0;
        for (var oa = 1; oa < 360; oa += other.precision) {
            var orads = oa * Math.PI / 180;
            x = other.x + (other.width * Math.cos(orads) * ocos - other.height * Math.sin(orads) * osin);
            y = other.y + (other.width * Math.cos(orads) * osin + other.height * Math.sin(orads) * ocos);
            ot.p2 = { x:x, y:y };
            var i = lt.intersect(ot);
            if (i) r.push(i);
            ot.p1 = ot.p2;
        }
        ot.p2 = { x:other.x + (other.width * ocos), y:other.y + (other.width * osin) };
        var i = lt.intersect(ot);
        if (i) r.push(i);
        return r;
    },
    draw: function(ctx)
    {
        var cos = Math.cos(this.angle), sin = Math.sin(this.angle);
        var p0 = { x:this.x + (this.width * cos), y:this.y + (this.width * sin) };
        ctx.beginPath();
        ctx.moveTo(p0.x, p0.y);
        for (var a = 1; a < 360; a += this.precision) {
            var rads = a * Math.PI / 180;
            var x = this.x + (this.width * Math.cos(rads) * cos - this.height * Math.sin(rads) * sin);
            var y = this.y + (this.width * Math.cos(rads) * sin + this.height * Math.sin(rads) * cos);
            var p1 = { x:x, y:y };
            ctx.lineTo(p1.x, p1.y);
        }
        ctx.closePath();
        if (this.fill) {
            ctx.fillStyle = this.fill;
            ctx.fill();
        }
        if (this.stroke) {
            if (this.lineWidth) ctx.lineWidth = this.lineWidth;
            ctx.strokeStyle = this.stroke;
            ctx.stroke();
        }
    },
    drawIntersections:function(other, ctx, color, width)
    {
        var intersections = this.intersect(other);
        ctx.fillStyle = color || 'white';
        if (width === undefined) width = 5;
        for (var i = 0; i < intersections.length; ++i) {
            ctx.fillRect(intersections[i].x - width / 2, intersections[i].y - width / 2, width, width);
        }
    }
};

function cloud(x, y, width, height)
{
    this.x = x;
    this.y = y;
    this.width = width;
    this.height = height;

    var center = { x: x + width / 2, y: y + height / 2 };
    if (Math.random() >= .5) {
        var diagonal = new line(x, y, x + width, y + height);
        var disth = diagonal.distanceTo(new vector(this.x + width, this.y), true);
    }
    else {
        var diagonal = new line(x + width, y, x, y + height);
        var disth = diagonal.distanceTo(new vector(this.x, this.y), true);
    }
    var distw = diagonal.length / 2;
    var angle = diagonal.angle;
    this.cover = new ellipse(center.x, center.y, distw, disth, angle, 'white', 'white');
    this.body = this.cover.clone().inflate(5).setStroke('black 1px');
    this.puffs = [];
    var a = Math.random() * Math.PI / 12;
    while (a < Math.PI * 7) {
        var p = this.cover.pointAt(a);
        var w = (.1 + Math.random() * .2) * (distw + disth) / 2;
        this.puffs.push(new ellipse(p.x, p.y, w, w, 0, 'black 1px', 'white'));
        a += .75;
    }
}

cloud.prototype =
{
    draw:function(ctx)
    {
        this.body.draw(ctx);
        for (var i = 0; i < this.puffs.length; ++i) {
            this.puffs[i].draw(ctx);
        }
        this.cover.draw(ctx);
    }
};

var canvas = document.querySelector('canvas'), ctx = canvas.getContext('2d');
canvas.width = canvas.offsetWidth;
canvas.height = canvas.offsetHeight;
var cloud = new cloud((canvas.width - 300) / 2, (canvas.height - 100) / 2, 300, 100);
cloud.draw(ctx);
```

```css
body {
  margin: 0;
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh;
  overflow: hidden;
  background-image: linear-gradient(to bottom, #2688FF, #94C4FF 75%, #B8D8FF);
}

canvas {
  width: 100vw;
  height: 100vh
}
```

```html
<canvas></canvas>
```

NOTES:

1. I've gone for a tilted ellipse thinking that the maths would be easy enough. Boy was I wrong! The maths may be easy enough, but my mathematical skills are rubbish. I tried several times to derive the equations to find the intersection points between two possibly rotated ellipses and I always ended up with a rational expression that I didn't know how to simplify :-( In the end I gave up and decided to approximate the ellipses as series of line segments, finding the intersections between those. Any help deriving the correct equations would be greatly appreciated.
2. Likewise, once I found the intersections between each added "puff" and the larger "body" ellipse, I tried to find their corresponding "angles" with respect to the center of the ellipse, so that I could choose the one with a greater angle and keep adding random puffs in a clockwise direction until I circumvented the whole body ellipse. However, I could not figure out how to calculate that angle so I place random sized puffs at fixed intervals that have nothing to do with π and do several revolutions, so the puffs overlap at apparently random places.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I like your approach. Here's an idea to improve it so the result would both cover the rectangle and have the desired notches:

1. **create an ellipse that has some tilt but covers the whole rectangle.** If you don't want to bother about tilt, you can use the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433371/ellipse-bounding-a-rectangle) to get an ellipse that covers the rectangle. For example, using [the insight](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ellipse#Equations) that the basic ellipse equation is actually a stretched equation for the unity circle you can just use it with parameters according to your rectangle: `(x/a)^2+(y/b)^2=1`, where `a:=rectangle.width/sqrt(2)` and `b:=rectangle.height/sqrt(2)`.
2. **make a copy of the ellipse and enlarge it** (stretch it) a bit in both axis. You can use a percentage, like 5% stretch in both axis.
3. **do with the big ellipse what you did before** - start at a random point on its circumference, put there a randomly sized circle, calculate its intersection with the ellipse and put new randomly sized circle with a centre there and continue until you covered the whole circumference. **This time - use circles that have a black stroke to them.**
4. **bring the original ellipse (the small one) to the front** of the whole collection of shapes.

So at the end you are left with the original smaller ellipse covering the rectangle and obstructing the rest of the circles' strokes and the enlarged ellipse together with the circles make the desired outline with notches inside the shape.

Comment: Thank you et_l. I have done a proof of concept that you may want to tweak a bit. Your suggestion has been very helpful.

Comment: I just wanted to add, it would be better just to draw a bunch of randomly sized ellipses with a stroke value along an ellipse and then draw a bunch of randomly sized ellipses along a smaller ellipse with no stroke. That way all the lines aren't so even. You could even do it along a curve instead of ellipse. And you should make those outside circles larger relative  so it doesn't look so lumpy.