# How to find the the largest rectangle able to fit within an ellipse of known dimensions?

Tags: javascript, algorithm, geometry

More specifically: given an ellipse with a known width, height and x, y position—how does one find the width, height and x, y position of the largest possible rectangle able to be drawn with in it.

```
// eWidth, eHeight, eX, eY are known, arbitrary values
const ellipse = draw.ellipse(eWidth, eHeight).move(eX, eY);

// rWidth, rHeight, rX, rY are unknown
const rect = draw.rect(rWidth, rHeight).move(rX, rY);
```

Comment: Sounds like Math

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/433371/ellipse-bounding-a-rectangle

Comment: I'm not looking for an ellipse bounding a rectangle. I'm looking to find the largest possible rectangle to fit inside of an already known ellipse.

Comment: By "largest" you mean by area?

Comment: Largest = largest area, yeah.

Comment: @dzuc should be same formula.... just solve it differently

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Alright just looking at this image made it clear:

[image]

From this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/6716520/160937

```
// eWidth, eHeight, eX, eY are known, arbitrary values
const ellipse = draw.ellipse(eWidth, eHeight).move(eX, eY);

// Each radius * Square root of 2
const rect = draw.rect((ellipse.width() / 2) * Math.SQRT2, (ellipse.height() / 2) * Math.SQRT2)
  // Then move to the center of the ellipse
  .cx(ellipse.cx()).cy(ellipse.cy());
```